# how can i compare two arrays and replace by date?

Tags: php, laravel

array: 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-09
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-08
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-07
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-06
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-05
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-04
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-03
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

)
```

---

array: 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-09
            [verify] => 10
            [unverify] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-08
            [verify] => 2
            [unverify] => 5
        )

)
```

I Want This type of array at last.

---

result:

```
Array
(
    
   [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-09
            [verify] => 10
            [unverify] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-08
            [verify] => 2
            [unverify] => 5
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-07
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-06
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-05
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-04
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2022-12-03
            [verify] => 0
            [unverify] => 0
        )

)
```

please help...

this is two array i want to compare(or anything) both array so i get my result what i want.
in array 2 of all records are replace by date(index) in array 1 so i get result

Comment: Have you tried anything like e.g. for each entry in the first array if there's an entry in the second array with the same date replace the first array  `verify` and `unverify` values with the ones of the 2nd array (i.e. a foreach loop in another foreach loop)? This seems like something you should be attempting on your own before asking for help

Answer (score 0):

```
// The arrays to compare
$array1 = [1, 2, 3];
$array2 = [4, 5, 6];

// The callback function that will be applied to each element of the arrays
function compareAndReplaceByDate($value1, $value2) {
  // Compare the values of the two arrays
  if ($value1 > $value2) {
    // If the first value is greater, return the date
    return date('Y-m-d');
  } else {
    // Otherwise, return the second value
    return $value2;
  }
}

// Use array_map() to apply the compareAndReplaceByDate() function to each element of the arrays
$result = array_map('compareAndReplaceByDate', $array1, $array2);

// Print the resulting array
print_r($result);
```

Comment: array_map(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function \"compareAndReplaceByDate\" not found or invalid function name ->return this error